# Copy of an custom np.ndarray edits original

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I wrote a custom class which inherits from np.ndarray (simplified example), I want to create a copy of the array, modify it without destroying the original and return it as new instance of Custom class.

However when I run the code original array is altered exactly as it's copy.

```py
class Custom(np.ndarray):

    def __new__(cls, array_like):
        obj = np.asarray(array_like, dtype=object).view(cls)
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return


@dataclass
class Empty:
    """ Stores constants. """
    pass


@dataclass
class Values:
    """ Stores constants. """
    pass


class Cell:

    def __init__(self, value: Empty | Values):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.value)


def modify(instance: Custom, move_from: tuple, move_to: tuple):
    new_instance = np.copy(instance)
    moving_cell = new_instance[move_from].value
    new_instance[move_to].value = moving_cell
    new_instance[move_from].value = Empty()
    return new_instance


custom_1 = Custom([[Cell(Empty()), Cell(Empty()), Cell(Empty())],
                   [Cell(Empty()), Cell(Values()), Cell(Empty())],
                   [Cell(Empty()), Cell(Empty()), Cell(Empty())]])
custom_2 = modify(custom_1, (1, 1), (0, 0))
print(custom_1)
print(custom_2)
```

Found the problem, i altered value of class Cell, which was not copied.

Comment: `np.array` has a `copy=True` parameter; `np.asarray` does not make a copy if it doesn't have to.

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete.  I can't test it or demonstrate the behavior.

Comment: Needs a [mcve].

Comment: Added the example, however while doing so I sort of figured out what was the problem, thanks.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, is that `numpy` array copy is fine for numeric dtypes.  And like lists, it makes a shallow copy of object dtype arrays.  `copy.deepcopy` is needed to make a deep copy of the objects in the array.

Comment: Yeah that was exactly the case, i used to modify instance which was assigned to both arrays.

Comment: numpy arrays have a `.copy()` method that should be preferred over the "deepcopy" module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use copy library:

```
import copy
second_array = copy.copy(first_array)
second_array = copy.deepcopy(first_array)enter code here
```